# Compile/make last modified cpp files first

Tags: c++, makefile

When I work on a cpp file, I often have to change header files referred to by that cpp file. For example, say I have three files:

```
common-headerh      [file referred to by both cpp files]
file1.cpp
file2.cpp
```

In my make file I have commands equivalent to:
    g++ -std=c++0x file1.cpp file2.cpp

I want to have a makefile that automatically reorders compilation order so that recently modified files are compiled first. In other words, if file1.cpp was most recently modified, I want my make file to do:

```
g++ -std=c++0x file1.cpp file2.cpp
```

However, if file2.cpp was more recently modified, I want the make file to do INSTEAD:

```
g++ -std=c++0x file2.cpp file1.cpp
```

How can I do that in an automated fashion? Answers specific to a particular IDE/build environment are also welcome.

---

**********Background**********

I have a large project (takes about 7 minutes to compile) and a lot of my code resides in templates in header files [in the example above that would be common-header.h]. As you well know, template code is not - more precisely, cannot - be compiled without a referring .cpp file. Say I want to add a new feature in file2.cpp and I end up coding it with templates. This means I am forced to put my new code in common-header.h. This new bits of code are, naturally, only compiled when file2.cpp is compiled. However, since the header file has been modified file1.cpp also needs recompilation. This is all fine, but say I have made an elementary typo in my new template code in common-header.h. Then I have to wait for the entire file1.cpp to compile before file2.cpp. However, if file2.cpp was compiled first, I would know immediately of my typo, without needing to wait for the compilation of file1.cpp.

Of course, one quick solution would be to just recompile file2.cpp manually. However, all bug fixing takes place in the header file: file2.cpp is not the window on focus in my IDE. So, I have to navigate to the correct cpp file that refers to the common-header.h and recompile from there. Not to mention I often simply confuse the compile shortcut with the build shortcut, have to abort the build, naturally being distracted. Or, I simply give up and go to youtube to wait for the whole build, resulting in terrible productivity.

Thanks for your advice

Comment: Why must the templates needed only by `file2.cpp` be defined in a header which must be included by `file1.cpp`? If the templates are needed only by `file2.cpp`, why must they be placed in a header file at all?

Comment: You are right I was oversimplifying. In reality it's a lot more complex. Usually, file1, file2, ..., file20 don't use the template but include the header. Then file21, file22, ... file25 use the template. As long as more than one file uses the header it must be in a header file (standard says so).

Comment: You can of course make an "implementation header"  - an optimization I already use - a second header only included by file21, ..., file25. However, making such implementation headers usually take multiple hours of code refactoring - in fact I am searching for easier alternatives (hence my question).

Comment: It sounds as if you have a codebase that is badly overcoupled, and you're looking for a clever way to suppress the symptoms rather than taking the time to correct the underlying problem.

Comment: Nah, my system is the best one in the world, it's C++'s fault it compiles slowly. Just messing around of course, whether my system is good or bad is a different question from the one I originally posted.

Answer (score 0):

There's no silver bullet to reduce compile time just like that, especially with templates, only general approach. You should look if you could reduce code coupling, break up headers into several files, so that changes do not affect the whole project. If you change the header that is included everywhere, it's expected to recompile everything. You could also try to move the functionality you're currently modifying in separate from entire project files, so that the compiler wouldn't have to recompile unchanged code again and again as you make changes. Also, use precompiled headers, if it's an option for you.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of using a bash script for that, for example:

```
ls -tr
```

this already gives the files in a folder ordered from most recent, if you have other files you can use grep to retrieve only .cpp.

With this you can already form the g++ command.

If before the command in the Makefile you add a comment:

```
#replace
g++ -std=c++0x file1.cpp file2.cpp
```

Then using sed you can locate and replace the order with something like

```
NEWCMD=$( ls -tr your/directory | grep .cpp )
NEWCMD="g++ -std=c++0x $NEWCMD"
sed '/#replace/!b;n;c$NEWCMD' Makefile
```

You need to run this before the Makefile though, but Makefiles admit some bash, so maybe there is a way to just put it there and don't have to call sed.

I haven't tested this, but couldn't post a comment yet :)

Comment: I use QT creator, I think I can tell it to do some bash before the makefile, not 100% sure.

Answer (score 0):

What about directing make to build the file you're most interested in?

> one quick solution would be to just recompile file2.cpp manually

And automatically is always better, right?  How about a little script called, say, `make1`?

```
#!/bin/sh
tgt=$(ls -t *.cpp | sed '1 s/\.cpp$/.o/; q')
make $tgt && make
```

Of course, `$tgt` need not be a single file; it could be all files in time order.

I'm simplifying; your source tree may have objects in several places.  But, if you can enumerate them and sort them by modification time, you can identify the "most interesting" target.

Comment: I just tried your script but I can't get what it does: can you explain? I have difficulty decoding '1 s/\.cpp$/.o/; q'

Comment: `1` is an addr; it means the code operates on the first line of input (the newest file).  `s/\.cpp$/.o/` is the command to replace the filename's ending substring of *.cpp* with *.o*.  The result is automatically printed.  Then `q` tells sed to quit. To print, say, the first 5 lines, you could use `s/\.cpp$/.o/; 5q`.

Comment: I played using your solution from the command line and it seems it is working as advertised. I have yet to make it into a fully functional script [best via make]. Thanks for the replies! [going back to see if the build has finished]